# Rails with JQueryMobile - Double render with send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create dynamically csv file with this code in the reports controller:

```
  def exportCsv
    @report = Report.find(:all)

     csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
       csv << ["id","cod_user_id","city","address","urgent level","description"]
       @report.each do |r|
        csv << [r.id,r.cod_user_id,r.city,r.address,r.urgent_level,r.description]
       end
      end

    send_data csv, :type => 'text/csv', :disposition => "attachment; filename=list.csv"
  end
```

The code of link in the show.html.erb file is:

```
<a href="<%=url_for :controller=>"reports",:action =>"exportCsv"%>">Clicca qui</a>
```

when i click the link, the download does not start and a white page appears. The download starts only if i refresh the white page. When i click the download link I want that the currently open page remains open and download starts.

**UPDATE I**
I use jquery.mobile-1.3.1 if i not use jquery mobile it work, the download starts and  the current page will remain open but if i use jquery-mobile the link not work in the correct mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add data-ajax="false" to your link's attributes. By default links are loaded with Ajax in jQuery Mobile.

```
<a data-ajax="false" href="<%=url_for :controller=>"reports",:action =>"exportCsv"%>">Clicca qui</a>
```

According the docs you can also use rel="external" which will also prevent Ajax loading. The difference between the two is semantic: rel="external" should be used when linking to a url outside your domain while data-ajax="false" is for internal links.

Comment: voting the answer up and accepting it is also a great way to say "Great! It works! Thanks" :)

Comment: I also recommend changing the question title since it is not a RoR issue.

Comment: you are right but i don't have enough reputation point to vote your answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
send_data csv, :type => 'text/csv', :disposition => "attachment", :filename => "list.csv"
```

From the `send_data` documentation (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data):

```
:disposition - specifies whether the file will be shown inline or downloaded. 
   Valid values are ‘inline’ and ‘attachment’ (default).
```

Comment: i tried it but doesn't work. the download not start if  you don't refresh the page after clicked the link.

Comment: the problem is jquery mobile